# Align Options in Select box to Left where Select Style is 'direction:rtl'

Tags: css, jsp

In my JSP page I have a select box

```
<select id="subjectArea" name="subjectArea" class="inputstyle">
    <option value="choose"><s:text name="global.generic_feed_target_choose" /></option>
    <option value="subjArea">Subject Area</option>
</select>
```

Its CSS is

```
select.inputstyle{
    width: 177px !important;
    height: 26px !important;
    margin-top: 5px !important;
    direction: rtl !important;
}
```

But the problem is, the options in the select box is also right aligned.

[image: You can see here]

I want the options to be aligned in the left. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need something like this? If yes than use `text-align: left;` to align the text in the option box to left, if you are looking for something else, than please let me know as your question is not very clear

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nxTTd/)

```
select.inputstyle{
    width: 177px !important;
    height: 26px !important;
    margin-top: 5px !important;
    direction: rtl !important;
    text-align: left;
}
```

> Note: You are not closing the `name` attribute -> `name="subjectArea"`

Comment: I tried. It's not working. When I copied the code here and edited mistakenly double quote gone. :)

Comment: I saw. And I tried it before also. it didn't work. I am wondering why

Comment: @ShijuKBabu But is that what you need?

Comment: Oh! It's working in Firefox but not in Google Chrome. I cleared the history of Chrome and tried. But not worked.